# Повесить несколько Button-ов на один обработчик

Tags: android, kotlin

Пишу калькулятор на Котлин. Есть отдельные Button-ы, мне нужно, чтобы мне не приходилось каждому отдельно прописывать setOnClickListener.

Comment: инструкция про [три способа обработать клики](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php) на кнопках и несколько в одном обработчике

Comment: тег android-studio ставится для вопросов с проблемами в самой программе, а не с тем, что вы с ее помощью делаете

Comment: @pavlofff лучше не постить ссылки, они протухают. Вместо этого приведите основной текст цитатой, а ссылку как источник.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко, то применить интерфейс `View.OnClickListener` ко всему классу `Activity / Fragment` целиком и там перебирать значения `swich view get Id`